# Has-Many-Through Relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have done a lot of research in Google about this. There are not a good examples with using this type of relation between models.

Can somebody share own sample using Has-Many-Through Relations in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a sample of a social network where you have User, their Friends and their friends' Photos. 3 models. yep a friend is just a normal user but for this example, a Friend would be a separate Model.

1- A user has friends

```
public function friends() {
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class);
}
```

2 - A friend has photos

```
public function photos() {
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

3 - You are the admin. you have many users, including John. John has a lot a friends. So sometimes, you want to see John's friends photos, maybe those where they tag him. So in user you define the relationship

```
public function friendsPhotos() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Friend::class, Photo::class); //could add a scope here for picture with tags only. 
}
```

Not problably the best example. But it shows how you can see all John's friends pictures by just doing

```
$john = User::where('email', 'john@email.com')->first();
$john->friendsPhotos();
```

If the example doesnt suit you well, now think of a bank looking for their best salesperson in a specific Branch. A Branch hasMany Salesperson, and each Salesperson hasMany Customers they deal with.

In Branch model, you define

```
public function customers() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Salesperson::class, Customer::class);
}
```

I hope this helps a little bit.

**Database tables for the banking system**

1- Branch

```
id
name
...
```

2 - Salesperson

```
id
branch_id
firstname
...
```

3 - Customer

```
id
salesperson_id
firstname
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please, describe tables, it is important

Comment: Check my update for tables, and if my answer helped, please, mark it as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure! Okay! But where is teble Photos? And what is table `Branch`?

Comment: I talked about 2 different systems: Friends & Bank. The tables I gave you are about the bank system. Branch is a branch of the bank. Banks have many branches, usually in different suburbs.